# I want to put a video on the main page

Tags: video, mp4

I want to put a video on the main page, the file size is 496MB, how to download this file. Now the movie is on the computer. I need good quality The video should be 100% width and height. I am using VSC editor. Detailed instructions please.

```
import React from "react";

const HomeMovie = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <section className="homeMovieContainer">
        <div className="homeMovieTittle">
     
        </div>
        <div className="homeVideo">
          <video src="./../assets/Movie.mp4" controls>
          </video>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomeMovie;

@import "src/scss/settings/_variables.scss";

.homeMovieContainer {

      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;

      video {
        object-fit: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You're not making sense. Does "download" mean how to play the file or how to make it smaller (_ie:_ compression)? You hae to keep the app and the file together or else put the file on the internet (get web space and store it there, using its http link to play it)...